# Is there a way to stop the Scenario Execution in Cucumber when a specific condition is met?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Currently in our automation framework we need to have a capability from which we can control the execution of scenario steps in cucumbers.

Problem Details :

Let's say we have below steps as a part of our scenario :

1. Check if Order exists
2. Create Order

What I want to achieve is to have a check in Step 1, if order exists in the system(via DB Call) just skip the whole scenario and mark it as pass/skipped. We do not want to place orders, if there are already
some which meets the criteria.

Currently I am handling it by placing an `Assert.false()` , If I get the Id from DB , it fails the assertion saying the ID already exist.

But this depicts the test as failed which is not correct from reporting perspective. Is there a way I can mark the test as passed/skipped for this scenario and stop the execution if order exist in the system.

Unfortunately I could not find something like an Assert.pass() through which I can exit the scenario and mark it as pass.

I am using cucumber with Java in a Maven project. Any leads or existing documentation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So if you throw a Cucumber Pending exception tests will abort.

In ruby there is also a nice neat `skip_this_scenario` Worldable method. Which does this for you and marks it as skipped.

For Java to throw the Pending exception just use `throw new PendingException();` I'm not sure if the skip scenario logic exists there. But if you trawl through the codebase you might find it. I've asked in slack to the core maintainer, feel free to join the slack group cucumberBDD - If you want to learn more. Or the docs site (docs.cucumber.io)

Luke - Cucumber Ruby maintainer

EDIT: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/testng#skipexception - For how to skip execution mid test

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what test runner are you using but in junit5 , I just use [`Assumptions`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assumptions.html#assumeFalse-boolean-) class like below

```
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions;

 ....

@Given("an employee record is created with values")

    public void create_employee_record(){

       // i'll just pass false as the parameter but it could be any method that retuns false

        Assumptions.assumeTrue((false));
      ...
     //more code here
      
}
```

The above scenario will not execute after validation of `Assumptions.assumeTrue((false))` and execution will continue to next scenario. In report this will be marked as aborted with other scenario marked as passed

[image]